# Accessing Objective-C structure from Monotouch while binding to iOS static library

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have some 3rd Party iOS Static Library which has .h files containing `const struct`:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    __unsafe_unretained NSString * const FirstName;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString * const SecondName;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString * const ThirdName;

};

extern const struct SomeStruct someName;
```

I bound this static library to MonoTouch, but I did not understand how to replicate this in C# and access the string value from that structure.

In MonoTouch iOS Binding Project

```
public struct SomeStruct
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string SecondName;
    public string ThirdName;

};


[Static]
public interface SomeInterface
{

    [Field ("SomeStruct", "__Internal")]
    IntPtr someNameStr { get; }
}
```

I included the dll generated by iOS binding Project in my demo application

To access the structure

```
    public static SomeStruct Name {
        get {
            if (SomeInterface.someNameStr != IntPtr.Zero) {
                return (SomeStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure<SomeStruct> (SomeInterface.someNameStr);
            }
            return new SomeStruct ();
        }
    }
```

Here I am able to get the proper IntPtr. But I am unable to convert it into Structure and access the members in the structure.

```
SomeInterface.Name.FirstName;
```

So, could someone please help me in doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the methods in Dlfcn to get the address of the *someName* address.   Use dlopen to open the library and dlsym to fetch the address.

Then you can marshal the result using Marshal.PtrToStructure but you must make sure that the values are IntPtr, like this:

```
public struct SomeStruct
{
    IntPtr _FirstName;
    IntPtr _SecondName;
    IntPtr _ThirdName;
};
```

To get the strings, then you do:

```
    public string FirstName {
        get {
            return (string) (new NSString (_FirstName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to access the SomeStruct structure.

Comment: The PtrToStructre will do that.